# countup and countdown in a loop. android

Tags: android, eclipse, counter, countdown

I want to count from 1 till 15 for example and go from 15 till it reaches 1 and repeats the process... may you please help me complete? I tried everything. Instead of if, I tried While, it gave random numbers for some reason. This method only subtracts to 14. It won't completely countdown.

```
int counter = 0;
int total = 15;
number = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.number);


    final Timer c=new Timer();
    c.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (counter < total && timerHasStarted ) {


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                           number.setText("" +counter );
                            counter++;    

                        }
                    });

                }
              if (counter <= total && timerHasStarted ) {


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                           number.setText("" +counter );
                            counter++;    

                        }
                    });
                    if (counter == total && timerHasStarted) {
                        countingDown = true;
                      if(countingDown){

                            counter--;
                        }
                        else{
                            counter++;

                        }
                        //setting the text here
                        if(counter%15==0){    //only 0 when counter equals 0 or 15
                            countingDown=!countingDown; // starting the other direction at next time
                        }



                    }

                }}}, 1000, 300);

    timerHasStarted = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt provide the whole code but nevertheless

Your logic has a big flaw:first counter is 0 so the first if is gonna count it up because its under 15...it does so till it reaches the 15 then it does nothing...but here comes the second if now that counter is 15 it is executed making the counter back again to 14 so it alters between 14 and 15 the wohle time froom the point it reaches for the first time.

Heres my solution:

have a boolean like countingDown and set it to false at the beginning if it hits the 15 set it to true.

check this boolean what to do if countingDown is true/false.

like:

```
if(countingDown){
    counter--;
}
else{
    counter++;
}
//setting the text here
if(counter%15==0){    //only 0 when counter equals 0 or 15
    countingDown=!countingDown; // starting the other direction at next time
}
```

Cheers

Comment: May you please clarify more? Do I keep the first counting up code? Well, the  bizzare thing is that the total is = 15 but the counter never hits 15, it hits 14. I changed the counter to 1. Excuse me if I didn't understand you well, I'm new to this. I tried your example, but it seems to never count up in the first place. I hope you know what I want. I want the counter to reach total and then decrease till it reaches 1 which is it's original int and then count back up to 15 and stay repeating.

Comment: Yeah put this code inside your timer method and it will work for 0 and 15.

Comment: Well I did what you are telling me, It stays stuck at the total 15. it won't countdown. Thanks for bearing with me. :p Something isn't right. Please anymore help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally. I did it. Noob mistake :p

```
final Timer c=new Timer();
    c.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (counter <= total && timerHasStarted ) {


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                           number.setText("" +counter );
                              // removed counter++;

                        }
                    });
                    if (counter == total && timerHasStarted) {

                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                               number.setText("" +counter);
                                       // removed counter--;

                            }

                        });



                        }
                      if(countingDown){
                          countingDown = true;
                            counter--;
                        }
                        else{
                            counter++;
                            countingDown = false;
                        }
                        //setting the text here
                        if(counter%15==0){    //only 0 when counter equals 0 or 15
                            countingDown=!countingDown; // starting the other direction at next time
                        }



                    }

                }}, 1000, 300);
```